# How to Add items to the string.xml using edittext?

Tags: android

```
<string name="AAAAA">Select a item"</string>

<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>AAA</item>
    <item>BBB</item>
    <item>CCC</item>
    <item>DDD</item>
    <item>EEE</item>
    <item>FFF</item>

</string-array>
```

I want to add new item to the string.xml file using edittext.(user inputs).
Could someone please tell me the way to insert a value to XML in this case? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Comment: why you want to add it inside the strings.xml file? Any specific reason

Comment: I need to connect with one array using multiple spinners in different layouts.That's why i try to use the string.xml file.How can i do this..?

Comment: Accept the answer which u found correct for u... Click on the Tick below your answer... No one will help u future if u don't accept the correct one...

Comment: thankz Tareq.Sorry for that.I'm new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to edit string.xml file from code? If you need to make a string array, create a Array list of string in java code, and add the values to it from string.xml.

Comment: I think, the idea here is that these strings should be accessible after the application ends.

Comment: After application ends?? The code he put here, it seems he is trying the example of list view.

Comment: I need to connect with one array using multiple spinners in different layouts.That's why i try to use the  string.xml file.How can i do this..?

Comment: OK, Then create a static Array List in Java, u can access it from other classes also

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not possible. `string.xml` is compiled with all the other resource files to the `.apk` file. It can't be accessed at runtime. You can store your strings in SharedPreferences or create files on user's SD card.

Answer (score 0):

my idea is that store the values in ArrayList it is better option and u can also display in List.

All The Best

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

**I need to connect with one array using multiple spinners in different layouts.That's why i try to use the string.xml file.How can i do this..?**

=> Define a static ArrayList in separate class, and then add/delete value from it whenever you required from any activity.